# Dynamics NAV with Json.NET

Tags: json, visual-studio, microsoft-dynamics

I want to use Json.NET in a development in Dynamics NAV.
I'm not really sure how I have to proceed to install the nuget package in my visual studio 2012 so that I can use this packege
Any help would be nice !

I just created an empty project so I could use silution explorer
There I get the package nuget option
But when I try to install Json.NET I get this error :
La version de schéma de « Newtonsoft.Json » n'est pas compatible avec la version 2.0.30625.9003 de NuGet. Mettez à niveau NuGet vers la dernière version via la page http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=213942.

I do not know what to do !

Comment: I got a VS Update (4) and now it works - thanks

Answer (score 0):

To install nuget use: Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 9.0.1. What .net framework version you are using for the project? I would check if your NuGet console is up to date.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This better be a comment than an answer. Please earn enough reputation to be allowed to comment others posts.